# Error when compiling with the "GPR" dependency

Tags: ada, gnat

I see the following error when compiling an Ada project with GNAT Studio, using the project dependency "gpr.gpr".

Error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0ZBT.png)

Here is my project source code:

```
with "gpr.gpr";
project Default is
    for Soure_Dirs use ("src");
    for Object_Dir use "obj";
    for Main use ("main.adb")
end Default;
```

There is a line within gpr.gpr that is causing the error:
[error-on-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btDoV.png)

If I were to reference another dependency, such as "aws.gpr", everything works fine. However, "gpr.gpr" and any project that references it does not compile.

Output to: gprbuild -vP2 -P default.gpr

```
Process tree, phase 1
  Value_Of (library_type) is default "static"
  Value_Of (xmlada_build) is default "static"
  Value_Of (library_type) is default "static"
  Value_Of (xmlada_build) is default "static"
  Value_Of (library_type) is default "static"
  Value_Of (xmlada_build) is default "static"
  Value_Of (library_type) is default "static"
  Value_Of (xmlada_build) is default "static"
  Value_Of (library_type) is default "static"
  Value_Of (xmlada_build) is default "static"
  Value_Of (library_type) is default "static"
  Value_Of (gpr_build) is "C:\GNAT\2020\bin"
  ERROR: value %% is illegal for typed string %%
Done Process tree, phase 1, Success=FALSE
gpr.gpr:11:04: value "C:\GNAT\2020\bin" is illegal for typed string "build"
gprbuild: "default.gpr" processing failed
```

Comment: Can you confirm that no environment variable named `GPR_BUILD` or `LIBRARY_TYPE` has been set? Such an environment variable may, in this case, interfere with your build.

Comment: I confirm no environmental variable has been set with those names.

Comment: Just to confirm from my side: when I try to compile a project based on the given project source code it compiles without problems on GNAT CE 2020 (both on Windows and Linux).

Comment: You might want to try to compile from the command line using `gprbuild -vP2 -P default.gpr` to further isolate the problem (look for lines containing `Value_Of` and `C:\GNAT\2020\bin`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have placed the lines with Value_Of into the question. Please let me know if you would like the rest of the output or anything else.

Comment: Can you confirm that the output of `gprbuild` states `Parsing "C:\gnat\2020\share\gpr\gpr.gpr"` (i.e. uses the `gpr.gpr` project that ships with GNAT CE 2020). And reconfirm that `GPR_BUILD` is not mentioned in the output of the command `set` (Windows specific command-line utility).

Comment: OK, thanks! It turns out GPR_BUILD was in Windows Environment Variables. Very sorry I missed out on this before.

Comment: Ok, good to hear. I will add an answer such that the question will show up as having an answer in the question list (otherwise, people might think the question needs additional attention, which might be annoying for people scanning over the question list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to the original question, it appeared that an environment variable named `GPR_BUILD` was set while a scenario variable named `GPR_BUILD` is used by the project `gpr.gpr`. The error could be reproduced given the project file source and by executing on the Windows command line

```
> set GPR_BUILD=C:\GNAT\2020\bin
```

and then

```
> gprbuild -P default.gpr
gpr.gpr:11:04: value "C:\GNAT\2020\bin" is illegal for typed string "build"
gprbuild: "default.gpr" processing failed
```

For more info on scenario variables, see the GPRbuild user's guide, [section 2.4](https://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#scenarios-in-projects).